# javascript/jquery array interaction doesnt work after .on("click")

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

i have Problem with an ajax interaction

```
var json = [
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }, 
    { firstName: "Anna", lastName: "Smith" }, 
    { firstName :"Peter", lastName: "Jones" }
];

$(".container").append("<ul>");

// cycle through array and select each object in it
$.each(json, function(idx, object) {    
    $(".container").append("<li>" + object.firstName + " " + object.lastName + '<input type="submit" value="del"><input type="hidden" value="' + idx + '"></li>');
});

$(".container").append("</ul>");

$("li").on("click", "input", function() {
    var idx = $(this).next().val();

    json.splice(idx, 1);

// clear container
$(".container").text("");
$(".container").append("<ul>");

// cycle through array and select each object in it
$.each(json, function(idx, object) {    
    $(".container").append("<li>" + object.firstName + " " + object.lastName + '<input type="submit" value="del"><input type="hidden" value="' + idx + '"></li>');
});

$(".container").append("</ul>");
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dAJV/)

If I click delete everything works as expected. But if i want to delete the second item there is no response whatsoever.

Can anyone explain to me why that would be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you make sure the value is a number and not a string? also, make sure the "li" elements exist BEFORE you bind an event on them. by the way, your code is a complete mess :(

Comment: In the click handler, you're throwing away all the `$('li')` elements that you attached events to. Replace the event binding with `$('.container').on('click', 'li input', function() { ... })`.

Comment: In addition to what these other comments have said, you're doing some weird things in your code. You don't need to do `$(".container").append("</ul>");`. Also, you're not even appending the `<li>` elements to the new `<ul>` - you're appending them to `.container`. So you're ending up with an invalid structure

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with Ajax.

Comment: Also, it's unnecessary to empty the elements and re-append them. All you're doing is splicing the `json` array - instead of re-generating the items from that array, just use `.remove()` to remove that `<li>` - in the `input`'s click handler, use `$(this).closest("li").remove();`, as well as your `json.splice(idx, 1);`

Comment: that wouldn't do the trick. because the index of the array would be updated but the index of my li elements would not. for example: if i cleared the second entry my new array would have the entries 0, 1. but my li's would have the idx 0, 2.

Comment: @user2162742 Not true - if you remove an item from the array **and** remove the `<li>`, the indexes match up. It just takes out the step of having to regenerate things (which may or may not be necessary depending on how you are handling all this)

Comment: @user2162742 Sorry, that's assuming you don't use the hidden input and handle it like my answer. Sticking with your setup, you're absolutely correct, the indexes wont' match up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `li` elements you attached the click event handler to are removed from the screen when you clear the container.

You got event delegation *almost* right using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) but you're adding the event to elements that will no longer be on the screen after the update (the `li`s).

Try attaching the event to the container instead, changing to:

```
 $(".container").on("click", "li input", function() {
```

#### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cch4F/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to delegate it to the closest static parent.. in your case..`li` is not static, it is added dynamically..delegate it to  `.container` which is present in the document at the time when the element is appened in the doc..

replace this

```
$("li").on("click", "input", function() {
```

with

```
$(".container").on("click", "li input", function() {
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/9dAJV/1/)